# I am unable login in grooveshark via , i am not a premium user, do you think that is the reason

Tags: clementine

I am unable login in Grooveshark via Clementine. I am not a premium user, do you think that is the reason? I tried resetting the password, but it's still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

**"User ***@gmail.com doesn't have a Grooveshark Anywhere account"**

It's what it shows when I try to log in with my Grooveshark account. So **yes**, it seems you need to be premium to use Grooveshark through Clementine.